# Replicating folder structure for defined file types in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, loops

I need a script that copies only JPG files from a folder structure containing mixed file types on one drive to the same structure on an different drive. The script needs to create the same folder structure on the destination drive. The structure looks like this:

z:\source\01

z:\source\02

z:\source\03

With each numbered subfolder containing many mixed file types.

I need to recreate the numbered folders here D:\Sorted and copy only the JPG files to the new folders.

I'm a PowerShell novice and have been playing with bits of code from different sites and have just got myself in a mess.

This is the closest I've got, but I'm getting the error "Cannot bind argument to parameter "path" because it is null"

```
$srcfolder = "Z:\source\*"
$workfolder = "D:\Working"


foreach ($srcitem in $(get-childitem $srcfolder -filter *.jpg -recurse)) {

    $newPath = $_.FullName -replace [regex]::Escape($srcfolder),$workfolder


    Copy-Item -path $_ -Destination $newPath -Force

}
```

I'd be grateful for any help fixing this mess.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Copy-Item -Path "Z:\source" -Filter *.jpg -Destination "D:\Sorted" -Recurse
```

Comment: Much obliged! That makes things much clearer. I do have a habit of over complicating things!